# NO_DATA_FOUND EXCEPTION in two cursors - Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to be able to raise an exception as the title says.  The exception I have currently gives me this error:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (‘No rows found’);
                      *
ERROR at line 39: 
ORA-06550: line 39, column 23: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "`" when expecting one of the following: 
( ) - + case mod new not null others <an identifier> 
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> 
table avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum 
variance execute multiset the both leading trailing forall 
merge year month DAY_ hour minute second timezone_hour 
timezone_minute timezone_region timezone_abbr time timestamp 
interval date 
<a string literal with character set specification>
```

This is my code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAP SIZE 12000 
Declare 
v_model VARCHAR2(40);
v_carcategory VARCHAR2(40);
v_totalcars NUMBER;
v_maxdate DATE:=TO_DATE(1, 'J');
Cursor carcur IS 
SELECT * FROM i_car;
CURSOR c1(v_car_registration VARCHAR2) IS 
SELECT * from i_booking a
WHERE a.registration=v_car_registration;
Begin  
For car_rec in carcur
LOOP
v_maxdate:=TO_DATE(1, 'J');
for rec in c1(car_rec.registration)
LOOP
IF rec.date_reserved > v_maxdate 
then
v_maxdate:=rec.date_reserved ;
If car_rec.Cost <=50000 THEN v_carcategory := 'Budget Car';
End IF;
If car_rec.Cost BETWEEN 50000 AND 100000 THEN v_carcategory := 'Standard Car';
End IF;
If car_rec.Cost >=100000 THEN v_carcategory := 'Premium Car';
End If;
end IF;
v_totalcars := findtotalcarmodels (car_rec.model_name);
end loop;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Registration:'|| ' '|| car_rec.registration); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cost:'|| ' $' || car_rec.Cost); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Model Name:'|| ' '|| car_rec.model_name); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Car Category:'|| ' '||v_carcategory);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total number of Cars:'|| ' '||v_totalcars);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Most Recent Rental Date: '|| ' '||v_maxdate);
DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE; 
END LOOP; 
EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (‘No rows found’);
END;
/
```

I am not overly sure about the positioning of my exception.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that your `dbms_output.put_line` call is using Microsoft curly quotes rather than the standard single-quote character to delimit the string.  You need to use the standard character, not the Microsoft character (all your other strings appear to be using the standard character).

Taking a step back, it makes no sense to catch a `no_data_found` exception only to call `dbms_output`.  There is no guarantee that data written to `dbms_output` will ever be sent to the client application or that the client application will ever display it to a user.

It also doesn't appear that you have any code that would potentially raise a `no_data_found` exception.  Opening a cursor that returns 0 rows does not result in an exception.  If you expected to receive exactly 1 row, you could write a `SELECT INTO` statement and that would raise an exception if anything other than 1 row was returned.  If your goal here is to determine how many times you iterated through the loop, you could potentially use the `%rowcount` attribute of the cursor.

Finally, it would make thinks much clearer if you formatted your code so that lines were indented based on what block they were a part of.  Code like

```
FOR rec IN cursor
LOOP
  IF <<something>>
  THEN
    <<do something>>
  END IF;

  IF <<something else>>
  THEN 
    <<something else>>
  END IF;

  <<more stuff>>
END LOOP;
```

is much easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin.  It was the curly quote issue.  That's a bit of a pain.  I guess that's what I get for using Word as a text editor.